# RowEditing plugin: disable editing and actioncolumn delete icon

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

My app has a small backoffice with a grid to allow de admin edit a combobox list on a form.

The grid records can be edited with the rowediting plugin and deleted by clicking on a actioncolumn icon.

However, the combobox has an item that can not be edited because when is displayed on combobox fires an event that show another form field.

How to disable the ability to edit that item (update and delete with icon)?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/us6

Comment: So when row shows 'NOT EDIT' you don't want to allow editing & delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeedit` listener to prevent editing of a record by returning false.

```
beforeedit: {
    fn: function(event,editor){                   

    switch (editor.record.data.name) {
            case 'NOT EDIT':
            return false;
            break;
            default:return true;     
        }
    }
},
```

You can use `isDisabled` in `actioncolumn` to disable delete icon for a record:

```
isDisabled: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
    if (record.data.name =='NOT EDIT')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
},
```

Full Code:

```
var nameModel = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {fields: ['name']});               

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'numberStore',
    model:nameModel,
    data: {
        'items': [{
            'name': 'one'
        }, {
            'name': 'two'
        }, {
            'name': 'three'
        }, {
            'name': 'NOT EDIT'
        }]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});


var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width: 350,
    height: 220,
    border: true,
    title: 'Grid - item dblclick',
    itemId:'gridItemId',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('numberStore'),

    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        clicksToEdit: 2,
        pluginId: 'roweditingId',

        saveBtnText : "Save",

        listeners: {
            edit: function(editor, context, eOpts){
                var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridItemId')[0];                         
                var store = grid.getStore();  
                var txtColIdx = 1;                       
                var textfieldRef = context.grid.columns[txtColIdx].getEditor(context.record); 
                var tetxfieldValue = textfieldRef.getValue();
                context.record.set('name', tetxfieldValue);

                store.sync({
                    success : function(record, operation) {
                        console.log('OK');
                    },
                    failure : function(record, operation) {
                        this.store.rejectChanges();
                    }
                });

           },
           beforeedit: {
                fn: function(event,editor){                   

                    switch (editor.value) {
                        case 'NOT EDIT':
                            return false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            return true;     
                    }
                }
            },

           canceledit : function ( editor, context, eOpts ){

              }
           }
       },

        columns: [{
            text: 'name',
            name:'name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            sortable : false,
            hideable: false,
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            minWidth: 40,
            flex: 0.20,
            align: 'center',

            items: [{
                icon: 'delete.png',     
                tooltip: 'Delete record',
                isDisabled: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
                    if (record.data.name =='NOT EDIT')
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                },
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, rec) {
                          grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
                },                }]
        }],

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

[**Here**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/usi) is the working example.

Comment: Thanks ankit chaudhary. Works great. Just another detail. In your example, when I click on the disabled icon, RowEditing plugin is activated in row. Any idea how to solve this without using an alert or message window (which is also a solution that works).

Comment: Thanx for finding that bug,now i have updated & corrected the code in which delete functionality also working!!

Comment: Thanks ankit. Good Idea. Another small detail. With your upgrade, if I click on a different row of 'NOT EDIT', it is removed. Maybe something like that:                              handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, rec) {
                            if (rec.data.name =='NOT EDIT') {
                                  grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
                            }                   
                     }

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear. when I click on row one (two and three) actioncolumn icon, the row it is removed. store.removeAt (rowIndex) is supposed to do that?

Comment: Yes..this is what happening in handler function.You can delete the editable record.Is that what you want or not?

Comment: Yes. I better study the RemoveAt () method in Sencha docs. What was not to realize was how it worked in the row 'NOT EDIT'. It seems to be simple: the icon is disabled so it does not fire any event and therefore does not remove that row or show rowediting plugin editor. Once again, thank you ankit.

Answer (score 1):

Use beforeedit event and return false, if the row shouldn't be edited. For actioncolumn - just check in handler what record is edited and do appropriate stuff. Here is [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ush)

Comment: Thanks yorlin. Works very well.